# How can i Prevent caching in angular?

Tags: angularjs, caching

I want to prevent caching in angular.For that i set the cache property to 
false.After doing this i request the same url .But didn't send that request 
to my server.
Used  code for preventing,

```
  $http({
         cache : false,
         method: "GET",
         url   :"myurl";

                    }).success(function(data) {

                    }).error(function(data) {
  });
```

And code used for remove cache,

```
var $httpDefaultCache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
$httpDefaultCache.remove('myurl');

$http({
         cache : false,
         method: "GET",
         url   :"myurl";

                    }).success(function(data) {

                    }).error(function(data) {         
  });
```

can u help me?Please

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the dummy parameter in the URL so that URL become an unique by adding data into it. Passing `dummy` parameter in `params` array will not harm the `$http` get call.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'myurl',
    params: { 'dummy': new Date().getTime() }
})
```

This will ensure caching will not be done for your url.

Best option would be disable caching on server side [**link here**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1586)

Comment: ok thanks for ur reply...i already tried on this way...but is there any alternative way to handle this issue without passing time as param .

Comment: @AnilaJacob I'm sure there is no other way to do this on clientside..what is problem with this way..?otherwise you need to set caching on server side..

Comment: Hi pankajparkar,

Plz check thi like,
https://coderwall.com/p/40axlq/power-up-angular-s-http-service-with-caching

When i searching this issue all having same answer like set cache property to false  or remove from cache before requesting..But all are not working for me.Why this not working ?Is any version problem or anything?

Comment: @AnilaJacob you need to look at this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1586 .doing server side caching is best practice

Comment: Ok thanks  pankajparkar.....Now i continue with server side caching with following code  ServletResponse response ;response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);